# Add new user without password but not disabled

Tags: users, password, useradd

I need to add new users who are only supposed to be usable through SSH. When adding a user, they get added to the shadow file with an exclamation mark (`!`) instead of an asterisk (`*`), so they are "disabled" and sshd does not allow them to be used.

Is there a way to add a user without a password that is enabled by default?

I have tried using busybox' adduser command and it adds them with a `!`. Similarly, Gentoo's default useradd command will add them with a `!`.

Comment: `adduser <username> --disabled-password ` - just make sure to also use the `--home` and `--shell` options if they need a home directory and login shell as `adduser` doesn't create them by default.

Comment: @ResetACK Looks like my system (Gentoo-based) doesn't have the adduser command, and busybox' adduser doesn't use --disabled-password. On my Ubuntu VM it added it correctly though.

Comment: You might be SOL then :) what happens if you remove the `! ` from the shadow file? Can the user log in without a password?

Comment: @ResetACK Yes, manually editing the shadow file will make the account usable, but I'm trying to avoid that since automating will increase the amount of times I can screw something up. I figured out what I was doing wrong with the `*` though, so it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I can specify the encrypted password to add the user with

```
useradd -p '*' testuser
```

It wasn't working previously because I forgot that the shell tried to expand the asterisk when I was missing the single quotes.

It looks like I could also use

```
usermod -p '*' testuser
```

on an existing user to set the password to an asterisk as well.

Answer (score 0):

On alpine and other busybox based distributions where `adduser` behaves like this, you can create an account with a random password that you don't keep.

Do this by generating the password from `/dev/urandom` and turning it into text with `base64`, then echoing it twice, piping it into the adduser command (without the `-D` flag) so it enters and confirms the password during user creation.

```
pw="$(head -c 20 /dev/urandom | base64 | head -c 10)"
( echo "$pw"; echo "$pw" ) | adduser foo
```

Another option would be to replace the `!` with a `*` in the `/etc/shadow` file after user creation.

```
adduser -D foo
sed -i -e "s/^foo:!:/foo:*:/" /etc/shadow
```

Comment: But how will you setup ssh to signon to a user with an unknown password?

Comment: They must have a public key in their `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. This way they can log in using their private key by using `ssh -i /path/to/private_key_file`. 

This site seems to explain it well: https://devopsmyway.com/passwordless-ssh-using-public-key-and-private-key/

Comment: I think you need to create the user **with** a password, setup `ssh` then disable the password (or change the password to a very hard password with urandom). A 10 byte hard password is not terribly hard, though.

Comment: 64^10 you'd have to guess out of ~1,000,000,000,000,000,000 possible combinations, if you could make 1,000 guesses per second it would take ~32 million years to cover the possible password space.  If you had a cluster gnawing at this that gave you a million guesses per second, and the poor busybox SSH server could actually keep up, you'd still be in the thousands of years. :D